# Crystal Report com LEFT JOIN e WHERE

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports, join

Estou com um problema para fazer um *LEFT JOIN* no Crystal Reports. Pelo que pesquisei, é um problema de SQL clássico quando se usa critérios *WHERE* cruzando com o *LEFT JOIN*. Tentei resolver de todas as maneiras, mas não consegui.

São 4 tabelas relacionadas:
[OrcHDR]
[OrdemProducao]
[ItemNota]
[NotasFiscais]

Estou interessado num relatório com todos os pedidos com OP, INCLUSIVE os que ainda não foram faturados, com exceção de alguns que estão especificados

Aqui está o SQL:

```
SELECT 
"OrcHdr"."SPreco", 
"OrcHdr"."SCustosMat", 
"OrcHdr"."SCustosMO", 
"OrcHdr"."SCustosTerc", 
"OrcHdr"."SCustosImpostos", 
"OrcHdr"."SCustosComissoes", 
"OrcHdr"."SCustosFin", 
"OrcHdr"."SCustosVenOutros", 
"OrcHdr"."NomeAgencia", 
"OrdensProducao"."NumOrdem", 
"OrdensProducao"."Descricao", 
"OrdensProducao"."NomeCliente", 
"OrdensProducao"."TipoProduto", 
"ItemNota"."Fatura", 
"ItemNota"."Devolucao", 
"OrdensProducao"."DtEmissao", 
"ItemNota"."ValorTotal", 
"NotasFiscais"."NaturezaOperacao", 
"NotasFiscais"."Situacao", 
"OrcHdr"."NumOrcamento", 
"ItemNota"."NumOrdem"

 FROM   

(("TABELA"."dbo"."OrcHdr" "OrcHdr" 

INNER JOIN 

"TABELA"."dbo"."OrdensProducao" "OrdensProducao" ON 
"OrcHdr"."NumOrcamento"="OrdensProducao"."NumOrdem") 

LEFT OUTER JOIN 

"TABELA"."dbo"."ItemNota" "ItemNota" ON "OrdensProducao"."NumOrdem"="ItemNota"."NumOrdem") 

INNER JOIN 

"TABELA"."dbo"."NotasFiscais" "NotasFiscais" ON "ItemNota"."ObjID_Nota"="NotasFiscais"."ObjID"

 WHERE  

("ItemNota"."Devolucao" IS  NULL  OR "ItemNota"."Devolucao"<>'D') AND ("ItemNota"."Fatura" IS  NULL  OR "ItemNota"."Fatura"='F') AND 
("NotasFiscais"."Situacao" IS  NULL  OR "NotasFiscais"."Situacao"='N') AND ("NotasFiscais"."NaturezaOperacao" IS  NULL  OR  NOT ("NotasFiscais"."NaturezaOperacao" LIKE 'doa%' OR "NotasFiscais"."NaturezaOperacao" LIKE 'reme%'))

ORDER BY "OrcHdr"."NumOrcamento"
```

O que de fato está acontecendo é que só obtenho as OPs que já foram faturadas, ou seja, que estão presentes nas tabelas [ItemNota] e [NotasFicais].

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Tem certeza que é AND mesmo, e não OR ? (tou chutando, faltam detalhes na sua questão do que você precisa que aconteça).

Comment: É AND mesmo, todas as condições devem ser atendidas ao mesmo tempo. 

O que preciso é um relatório, em determinado intervalo de tempo, com informações de todas as "OrdensProducao"."NumOrdem", inclusive os que não estão presentes em ItemNota.

Comment: Pode ser o tipo de Join escolhido, não? Veja se isso ajuda: [Qual é a diferença entre inner join e outer join?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/70)

Comment: O Crystal Report entrou na história com Pilatos no Credo como dizem os antigos ...

Answer (score 1):

Acabei resolvendo meu problema trocando as ordens de relacionamento das tabelas.

Antes estavam assim:

```
[Orçamento]-[OrdemProducao] -> [ItemPedido]-[NotaFiscal]
```

Modifiquei para:

```
[Orçamento]-[OrdemProducao] -> [ItemPedido]
                            -> [NotaFiscal]
```

E tudo funcionou.

Obrigado aos que colaboraram!

Comment: Cassiano, como você mesmo descobriu, a ordem importa sim. A regra é simples: primeiro os inner joins e depois os outer joins.